# Select the whole <td> on click instead of only the <a> inside of it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table where I have some `<a>`'s, what I want: make clickable the full `<td>` which contains those `<a>`'s.

Pasting my code will explain what I want better

```
<td>
  <a><span>{{:: row.spread.spread}} ({{:: row.spread.moneyLine}})</span></a>
</td>
```

for now the only clickable area is the one with red border

[image]

Here my css

```
  td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: get-space(x-small) + 2;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    a {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

OK, all I need is take approach of the full `td` and make them clickable instead of only be able to click over the links, is that clear for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove padding from the `td` and add it to the `a`, like this:

```
td {
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    a {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: block;
        padding: get-space(x-small) + 2;
    }

}
```

Also, make sure you set `display: block` on the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery

```
$('td').click(function() { window.location = $('a',this).attr('href') });
```

add to your CSS to improve the UX

```
td { cursor: pointer }
```